# React UseState Boolean Array Modify One Element

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, boolean, use-state

I have a boolean array in useState

```
const [checkBoxState, setcheckBoxState] = useState([true,true,true,true,true,......]
```

I need a function that toggle only specific index value A function like this

```
const HanldeCheck = (index) => {
    setcheckBoxState[index] = !checkBoxState[index];
  };
```

Please Help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

maybe you can use something like this?

```
const HanldeCheck = (index) => {
    setcheckBoxState(prevState => prevState.map((item, idx) => idx === index ? !item : item))
};
```